# How to set child of class' property with using xaml? (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using xamarin.forms.

I have a class named AAStackLayout and it has a Image inside itself.

And I add AAStackLayout on my page called AAContentPage with using xaml.

So, How to access layout's Image from AAContentPage with using xaml so that I can change its bindable property?

somthing like :

AAContentPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage>
  <local:AAStackLayout>
    <local:AAStackLayout.MyImage>
      <source="AAA.jpg"/>
    </local:AAStackLayout.MyImage>
  </local:AAStackLayout> 
</ContentPage>
```

AAStackLayout.xaml

```
<StackLayout>
  <Image x:Name="MyImage"/>
</StackLayout>
```

What I want is to edit Image's bindable property that already added. I'm not trying to add new Image.

Also, I know I could add bindable properties same with Image and apply its to Image. But I don't think it's best way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use in your custom `AAStackLayout` in your `BindableProperty` one of the parameters `BindableProperty.BindingPropertyChangedDelegate`

```
private static void OnImageChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var yourStack = bindable as AAStackLayout;
    yourStack.MyImage = // use newValue
    // or
    yourStack.MyImage.Source = // use newValue
    // Don't know the type of your BindableProperty
}
```

What I meant:

```
public partial class AAStackLayout : StackLayout
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MyImageProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MyImage),
                                    typeof(ImageSource),
                                    typeof(AAStackLayout),
                                    default(ImageSource),
                                    propertyChanged: OnImageChanged);

    public ImageSource MyImage
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(MyImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyImageProperty, value); }
    }

    public AAStackLayout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static void OnImageChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var stack = bindable as AAStackLayout;
        stack.Image.Source = (ImageSource)newValue;
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CommonSample.AAStackLayout">
  <Image x:Name="Image" />
</StackLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CommonSample;assembly=CommonSample"
             x:Class="CommonSample.Page1">
  <local:AAStackLayout MyImage="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcReayFrJYeKHSMTsZcp4GA78zygyG7SBColupjra_YVLhznN2tx" />
</ContentPage>
```

I'm not sure that you could reach `<Image x:Name="Image" />` from XAML, but you could do next thing:

```
public partial class AAStackLayout : StackLayout
{
    public Image MyImage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Image;
        }
    }

    public AAStackLayout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And the work wtih `AAStack` from behind code:

```
var stack = new AAStackLayout();
stack.MyImage
```

Comment: Hi Egor. Thanks for reply. But I think this is not what i'm looking for. I want to set my custom class's member's property from ContentPage's XAML.

Comment: Thanks for editing answer. I already know what you suggested. But there is many another properties I want to use on Image. And I don't think putting BindableProperty codes for all those properties(like Aspect or many things) is not the best way. But it's good to know that you suggested that way. So there is no simpler way to set Image's property from xaml?

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I tried and noticed that I can't access the Image with using that way. Yes. It's right way to access it.