# How to set my custom class's member View's property from XAML? (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms.

I already asked question here.
[How to set child of class' property with using xaml? (Xamarin.forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198419/how-to-set-child-of-class-property-with-using-xaml-xamarin-forms/)
But I couldn't get right answer for this, or there may be no solution for that.

What I want to do is setting my class's view's property from ContentPage's XAML.
my class has some view like Image and else.

I searched and found that there is 'ControlTemplete'. But I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for.

And I also don't think putting BindableProperty and OnPropertyChangedDelegate codes for every property that I want to set is a best way.

Is there another better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: If you already know that the correct answer is wrong, why are you asking the question?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Hi, I don't think his answer is wrong. And I really appreciate to him. I want to know if there is another way or it was right answer and there is no other way.

Comment: And I also wrote about it on question. And seems like it was right answer. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of creating custom `Stack` instead of using `StackLayout` from box, put there `Image` and use all needed properties of `Image`?

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy I want to make some templete(here, my custom class based on StackLayout) and use it in anywhere. And I also want to set it's property and it's children's property from where I put(here, ContentPage).

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy More details are in the conversation with 'root' who answered below.

Answer (score 2):

You can map XAML that is inside your control to a property using ContentProperty attribute.

```
[ContentProperty("MyContent")]
public class MyControl : ContentView 
{
    public View MyContent { get; set; }
}
```

And in XAML somthing like this

```
<local:MyControl>
    <Grid></Grid>
</local:MyControl>
```

this limits you to only one property but should work with any types.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware that solution. But isn't it solution that uses when you add controls? I'm trying to set child controls' property that already added.

Comment: @BrightLee, not quite sure what you mean here. Your controls are constructed from XAML, you can set constructor arguments or pass a single content property during construction. Once it has been created you have binding to change it's properties from the model. Can you elaborate what is your scenario?

Comment: hm... In the XAML(I think it's MyContentPage.xaml) you gave and class you named 'MyControl', there is a View named MyContent. Let's say it is a Image, not a View. And Let's say MyControl is a some Layout like StackLayout. And MyContent(Image) is already constructed in MyControl.xaml. And MyControl is assigned in MyContentPage.xaml. Now, how can you set MyContent's 'Source' or 'Aspect' property at MyContentPage.xaml?

Comment: @BrightLee, Are you talking about passing parameters from page XAML to control XAML? Where a page sets a parameter on control and control uses this value on it's children?

Comment: Yes. And I don't want to create all BindableProperty each that I want to pass parameters to it's children.

Comment: @BrightLee, your original question hardly describes the problem as you present it in the comments here.

Comment: I'm sorry. So what's your suggestion?